# Changing the rows of a 2D numpy array to strings

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array and I want to change its rows into strings so that I'll have an 1D numpy array where each element corresponds to a string corresponding to a row of the 2D array. I feel like there should be an easy way to do this but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
import numpy as np

y = np.array([str(xx) for xx in x])
```

Where `x` is a 2D numpy array such as:

```
 x = np.array([
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9],
 ])
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the following.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
print(x.shape) # prints (3,3)

y = []
for row in x:
    item = ''
    for column in row:
        item = item + str(column)
    y.append(item)

y = np.array(y) 
print(y.shape) # prints (3,)
print(y)       # prints ['123' '456' '789']
print(y[1][1]) # prints 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy array is made to work with numbers. I would discourage its usage with strings or any other object, unless you really know what you are doing. Having said that,

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
>>> R = [np.array_str(a) for a in A]
>>> print R
['[ 0.  1.  2.]', '[ 3.  4.  5.]', '[ 6.  7.  8.]']
```

R there is a standar python list, which probably would suffice for most usages. If you really really want a numpy array, and you know what you are doing with it, you can just wrap the list:

```
>>> R = np.asarray(R, dtype=str)
```

Note that you could have also used the solution from @JoséSánchez, but [np.array_str](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.array_str.html) gives you much more flexibility to how you store rows as strings than calling `str`. E.g. you can set precission to X decimals or round small numbers to 0.